# is there a way to store data from one form then submit it with another?

Tags: javascript, php, email, storage

I am building a contact form that will send an email containing the data inputed. But it is suppose to contain data that has been inputed in a form which submit button is also a CTA that shows the contact form. Is there a way to store data written by user into the first form to then add it to the data written into the contact form ? Basicly the first form is a calculator and on user click it shows the result next to contact form. And upon filling that contact form the email needs to contain the info from calculator as well as the info from contact form.

Comment: Sure. Simply embed the data submitted by the first form as hidden html input fields to the second form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via hidden input fields or you can do the same with PHP sessions in the first form action pass the second form like this
`<form method="POST" action="form2.php">`
and with the use of the POST method. In the next step, submitted information will be stored in the session array.

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name']; ?>
```